# preg_replace to replace the number in substring php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have below string

```
$string = 'id="0000001" did="659" interval="2" media.jpg'
```

I want to replace 2 (value is dynamic 0 to 1000) in interval tag with 0. How can I do it?

I tried following code but it replaces all

```
$returnValue = preg_replace('/\\d+/', '0', $string, -1, $count);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$returnValue = preg_replace('/(?<=interval=")\\d+/', '0', $string, -1, $count);
```

Just include a `lookbehind` stating `interval="` should be present before the `\\d+` you are trying to find.

Comment: @BhumiShah use `(?<=interval=["'])\d+` for that

Comment: @BhumiShah `$re = "/(?<=interval=[\"'])\\d+/m";`

Answer (score 0):

This is an another way to do this without using lookbehind assertion however using lookbehind is much cooler.

```
preg_replace('/(interval=")(\d+)/','${1}0', $string, -1, $count);
```